# Rabin-Karp Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, rabin-karp

I have implemented the Rabin-Karp algorithm in C#.NET, following this pseudo-code:

[image: pseudo code]

The issue is, the pattern is not matched with the original text. I have thoroughly gone through the code, but I can not identify the issue in my code. Can someone show me the bug in my code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "ratcatpat catbats";
    string pattern = "cat";

    int d = text.Select(e => e).Distinct().Count();

    RabinCarp(text, pattern, d, 17);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void RabinCarp(string text, string pattern, int sizeOfAlphabet, int moduloValue)
{ 
    int rollingHashOf_P = 0;
    int rollingHashOf_T = 0;

    int lengthOfText = text.Length;
    int lengthOfPattern = pattern.Length;
    int h = (int)(Math.Pow(sizeOfAlphabet, lengthOfPattern - 1) % moduloValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfPattern; i++)
    {
        rollingHashOf_P = (sizeOfAlphabet * rollingHashOf_P + (int)pattern[i]) % moduloValue;
        rollingHashOf_T = (sizeOfAlphabet * rollingHashOf_T + (int)text[i]) % moduloValue;
    }

    int diffNM = lengthOfText - lengthOfPattern;

    for (int i = 0; i <= diffNM; i++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(rollingHashOf_P) == Math.Abs(rollingHashOf_T))
        {
            if (text.Substring(i, lengthOfPattern).Contains(pattern))
            {
                string message = "pattern identified";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }   
        if (i < diffNM)
        {
            rollingHashOf_T = Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_T - (int)text[i] * h) + (int)text[i + lengthOfPattern]) % moduloValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it ?

Comment: Please, most of us don't magically spot bugs as well. We have to do hard work to find bugs in our code, dissecting it, inspecting internal data structures, modularizing it, testing the different modules etc. In your case the first step would be to verify that the substring hashes are in fact computed correctly. You can extract the line `Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_T - (int)text[i] * h) + (int)text[i + lengthOfPattern])` into its own function and check whether it returns the same hashes for equal substrings

Comment: What bug?  Please provide details on what you expected.

Comment: @Aybe - Yes, I dubugged the code.

Comment: @NiklasB. - as you have mentioned I checked the hashes for eqaul substrings. And the hashes didn't match. according to the pseudo-code I think I have written it correctly. Following is the pseudo-code.

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/a5zLD.png

Comment: @Daniel - the pattern is not identified.

Comment: @user1457039 - you should add the pseudo code to your post, also see my updated answer, tell me if it takes you forward...

Comment: @UriAgassi - since my reputation is low, stackoverflow does not allow me put images on posts...I have added the link to the pseudo-code in my comment for you...thnkz

Comment: @DukelingKrisVandermottenRicocookiemonsterNiklas B. - why this is put on hold as off topic...I have added the pseudo-code to each of your comments. since stackoverflow is not allowing me to put the images into my post due to my low reputation...for your consideration here is the link for the pseudo-code http://i.stack.imgur.com/a5zLD.png

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'm not familiar with the Rabin-Karp algorithm, but I'm pretty sure you should advance `rollingHashOf_P` as well as that of `rollingHashOf_T`:</strike>

```
if (i < diffNM)
{
    rollingHashOf_T = Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_T - (int)text[i] * h) + (int)text[i + lengthOfPattern]) % moduloValue;
    rollingHashOf_P = Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_P - (int)pattern[i] * h) + (int)pattern[i + lengthOfPattern]) % moduloValue;
}
```

After the OP shared this pseudo-code in the below comment:

[image: pseudo code]

It is clear that the above is wrong. Comparing this with the code in the post, though shows the bug might be in the line advancing `rollingHashOf_T` after all, as it says:

```
rollingHashOf_T = Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_T - 
  (int)text[i] * h) + (int)text[i + lengthOfPattern]) % moduloValue;
```

While the pseudo-code suggests it should be:

```
rollingHashOf_T = Math.Abs(sizeOfAlphabet * (rollingHashOf_T - 
  (int)text[i + 1] * h) + (int)text[i + lengthOfPattern + 1]) % moduloValue;
```

Comment: According to the pseudo-code rollingHashOf_P is not needed inside the if statement. Here is the pseudo-code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a5zLD.png

Comment: @user1457039 You are right, of course, it does say `text[i+1]` and `text[i + lengthOfPattern + 1]` though...